# Upload blob audio file to aws ec2-instance using php

Tags: javascript, php, file, amazon-ec2, blob

I am creating a web application where user can record audio and then can upload it to the server.

I am able to record the audio and also was able to send the blob data to the server. But i cannot push file into the ec2-instance (aws hosting enviornment). I am attaching the php code.
I am not sure which path should i use.
Here is the Php Code.

```
<?php
    print_r($_FILES);
    $uploaddir = '/var/www/html/public/src/audio/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['audio_data']['name']);
    $size=$_FILES['audio_data']['size'];
    $input = $_FILES['audio_data']['tmp_name']; //temporary name that PHP gave to the uploaded file
    $output = $_FILES['audio_data']['name'].".wav"; 
    if(move_uploaded_file($input, $$uploadfile)){
    echo "uploaded";
    }
    else{
        echo $uploadfile;
    }?>
```

Is there a way to push data and create file on hosted aws-ec2 instance? Is there any changes required in the php file?

[This is the image of response from server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sscOE.png)

Comment: Is the php server running on this EC2 instance? If so, do you get any errors in your php log when these lines of code run? Often times it's a file size issue that has to be updated in your `php.ini`.

Comment: yes php server is running on ec2-isntance. when I am sending the data using ajax I am not getting error but move_uploaded_file is giving result false.

Comment: I also dont know the path which I should be using.